# Color highlighting different temperatures in different colors in the apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

i work in apex oracle, i want to do a backlight of temperature indicators, ie i have a table with a temperature, and i want to highlight it with color when several colors i know how to do it. But when I am over 20 I do not know. Here are photos of colors and temperatures.

[image]
  I would be grateful for the help if anyone helps with this task

Comment: What method are you using to get up to 20 colours?

Comment: Apex_MAN, did you still need help with this?